# When should I use SQLite, when Microsoft Access?

Tags: .net, sqlite, ms-access

I have to develop a Window based application in .Net.The application is provided to a single user, which can query the database to get the results. There is no modification in the database can be done by the user.
For installation, I need to make the application independent of any kind of sources. So for database concern I want to know which one is better in use:

SQL lite or MS Access?

As for MS Access I always need to take care of the Office version available on the system wherever the setup is being run.

Please suggest which would be good for me to go with & if any other option to make this portable.

Comment: Probably there is no kind of "remote hinting" without knowing a load full of specification and requirements for your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact).

It's an embedded database like SQLite, which means that it doesn't require an installation in the client like SQL Server Express. [You only need to distribute a few assemblies with your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356333/how-should-i-use-sql-server-compact-edition-in-a-sharpdevelop-project-on-multipl/5356898#5356898).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278104/sql-ce-sqlite-what-are-the-differences-between-them... what about this

Answer (score 1):

Only use MSAccess when you do not care about your data (i.e. - never).

Comment: And what if when office is not available on the installation machine or the version am using is not there with the office installed.

Comment: I have lost track of the number of times that I have seen people lose their data when using Access. It's just not a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) before MS Access.

If you can safely assume a Windows ecosystem, then that would be a fine choice.

SQL Lite runs on all major platforms, so it is certainly much more portable.

You need to provide more information about the users and your architecture before anyone can answer your question well.

Comment: Its is a single user application with read only architecture.

Comment: And for SQL server express edition, it need the system with respective framework to be there or the system is 32 bit or 64 bit & as per that what it can support & all. let me know if am wrong.

Comment: @Neha- yes, you need a system that supports SQL Server express in order to run SQL Server Express.  The minimum requirements are quite small by today's standards.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143680%28v=sql.90%29.aspx  If the target machines cannot handle that, then you need to choose an option that they can handle.  Without more detail on what you are trying to do, vague and general answers are all anyone can give you.